# HiddenField throwing error on HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

When I am adding a `HiddenField` control in `Page` object on server side and calling `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute`, the code is throwing error, however same code is running fine when using `Panel` object instead of `HiddenField`

Following is sample code for reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page pageHolder;
            pageHolder = new Page();

            Panel p = new Panel();
            HiddenField h = new HiddenField();
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(h);

            using (StringWriter l_SW = new StringWriter())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, l_SW, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception it is throwing is

> Control 'ctl00' of type 'HiddenField' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Don't know why this is happening with HiddenField only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like

```
 Page.Form.Controls.add(h);
```